# How to format a paper accepted to a conference?

Tags: cv

I was second author on a paper that was accepted to a large and somewhat prestigious conference--the first author was the one who presented it (as part of a panel, not a poster), but because I'm early in my career I'd still like to highlight it somewhere on my CV. I think I'll create a section like "Other Research" or "Other Papers" or something so it's not misleadingly put with peer-reviewed publications.

Does this sound like a good strategy? And how should I actually format the citation itself? Do I put "accepted at Conference X, presented by Name"?

Comment: I'd add for the completeness that there _are_ peer-reviewed conferences in the other fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you should list a conference paper as part of your CV. Just make sure that, as you suggested, that it’s separate from peer-reviewed publications. Usually, “conference proceedings” or “presentations” or a similar section heading is used, depending on what records are available.

As for format, use whatever is the accepted practice and format in your discipline.